# How to manipulate data from SOAP XML with regex

Tags: xml, linux, perl, curl, soap

I'm planning to write a script which gets data through SOAP. I can get a file which contains a lot of following data, example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns0:GetList_Operation_0Response xmlns:ns0="urn:TEST:AST:Attributes" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>Deployed</ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>
        <ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>OI-ASDAQWDASDWA</ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>
        <ns0:instanceId>OI-SDWDSDWDSDWD</ns0:instanceId>
        <ns0:ModifiedDate>2017-12-12T03:31:32+01:00</ns0:ModifiedDate>
        <ns0:ClassId>BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:ClassId>
    </ns0:getListValues>
    <ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>Being Assembled</ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>
        <ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>OI-ASDQWAWDSADW</ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>
        <ns0:instanceId>OI-SDWDSWDSWDWD</ns0:instanceId>
        <ns0:ModifiedDate>2017-12-10T03:30:21+01:00</ns0:ModifiedDate>
        <ns0:ClassId>BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:ClassId>
    </ns0:getListValues>
    <ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>Deployed</ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>
        <ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>OI-ASDWASDWDASDW</ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>
        <ns0:instanceId>OI-SDWDSDWDSDWD</ns0:instanceId>
        <ns0:ModifiedDate>2017-12-12T03:31:31+01:00</ns0:ModifiedDate>
        <ns0:ClassId>BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:ClassId>
    </ns0:getListValues>
</ns0:GetList_Operation_0Response></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Could you suggest how to only extract the status between "AssetLifecycleStatus", example: Deployed. And it should go through every part of this line and give output to a new line. Example:

Deployed

Being Assembled

Deployed

Which is the best language to manipulate such data, is it Perl?
Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3):

There's not really a best language for parsing XML. Perl is known for its regex but parsing XML is much better done with a dedicated parser. In perl, `XML::LibXML` is a widely used one. There are other parsers for Perl, as well as Python, Ruby, JS, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => *DATA);
    # can also load with (string => $xml_string) or (location => 'file.xml');
my @nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus');

for my $node (@nodes) {
    print $node->textContent."\n";
}


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns0:GetList_Operation_0Response xmlns:ns0="urn:TEST:AST:Attributes" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>Deployed</ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>
        <ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>OI-ASDAQWDASDWA</ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>
        <ns0:instanceId>OI-SDWDSDWDSDWD</ns0:instanceId>
        <ns0:ModifiedDate>2017-12-12T03:31:32+01:00</ns0:ModifiedDate>
        <ns0:ClassId>BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:ClassId>
    </ns0:getListValues>
    <ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>Being Assembled</ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>
        <ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>OI-ASDQWAWDSADW</ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>
        <ns0:instanceId>OI-SDWDSWDSWDWD</ns0:instanceId>
        <ns0:ModifiedDate>2017-12-10T03:30:21+01:00</ns0:ModifiedDate>
        <ns0:ClassId>BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:ClassId>
    </ns0:getListValues>
    <ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>Deployed</ns0:AssetLifecycleStatus>
        <ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>OI-ASDWASDWDASDW</ns0:ReconciliationIdentity>
        <ns0:instanceId>OI-SDWDSDWDSDWD</ns0:instanceId>
        <ns0:ModifiedDate>2017-12-12T03:31:31+01:00</ns0:ModifiedDate>
        <ns0:ClassId>BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:ClassId>
    </ns0:getListValues>
</ns0:GetList_Operation_0Response></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've got the [Mojolicious framework](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) installed, you can use the [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo) package to write a simple Perl one-liner. It's called `ojo` because when you use it one the command line with `-M`, it will become `-Mojo`.

This program assumes there's a file called `foo.xml` with your XML content in the same directory.

```
$ perl -Mojo -E 'x(f("foo.xml")->slurp)->find("AssetLifecycleStatus")->map(sub{say $_->text})'
Deployed
Being Assembled
Deployed
```

I'll walk you through the program.

```
perl                               # call the Perl interpreter
  -Mojo                            # load module ojo
  -E '                             # run the following program with all features turned on
    x(                             # ojo function to turn string into Mojo::DOM object
      f("foo.xml")                 # ojo function to create a Mojo::File object
        ->slurp                    # read in the whole file and return content
    )
    ->find("AssetLifecycleStatus") # find all instances of string in DOM with CSS selector
    ->map(                         # iterate and run on all instances ...
      sub {                        # ... this function ...
        say $_->text               # ... output text node of element with newline attached
      }
    )
  '
```

Comment: Of course this does not handle the SOAP part. You'd need something more sophisticated for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSLT 2.0 then use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*:AssetLifecycleStatus">
            <xsl:text>&#x000A;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT IS:

Deployed 
Being Assembled
Deployed

Comment: Not yet sure how to use it, I see that xsltproc is installed on our Linux machine though.